Why Android provides DexClassLoader？
Since Android developer Program Policies state that applications must not download unrestricted executable code from any source other than Google Play and introduce security vulnerabilities. But DexClassLoader just can do it.
So I can not understand why does android provides DexClassLoader for developer?

First, there is a matter of time. DexClassLoader was introduced in API Level 3, back in 2009 or thereabouts. The Play Store policy changes came out substantially later. For backwards compatibility reasons, Google rarely outright removes old APIs.
Second, there is a matter of choice. While the Play Store is popular, not all Android devices are part of the Google Play ecosystem. Other app distribution channels can have their own policies, and they may allow the use of dynamic code loading. Users can also "sideload" apps (i.e., installing directly rather than via an app store), and those apps could use DexClassLoader.
Note that Google themselves use DexClassLoader in Jetpack libraries, notably Privacy Sandbox. Google can exempt their own uses from their own policies. If they removed DexClassLoader from the public SDK, they might be able to work around it, but it would be a hassle.
